# how can i access an inner property in a TypeScript file that itself points to an array with Angular

Tags: angular

hi i'm new in angular and i want to display data from type script using angular.
and i have an object that itself points to an array of  objects .

type script file

```
const phones = {
    description: 'blablabla.',
    characteristics : [
        {
          rating: 5,
          name: "samsung",
          country: "south Korea"
          },
        {
          rating: 5,
          name: "iphone",
          country: "usa"
        },
        {
          rating: 4,
          name: "meizu",
          country: "china"
        }
    ]
    };
```

html file

```
<div  *ngIf="phones">
       <p>{{phones.description}}
                </p>
                <md-list *ngIf="phones">
                    <md-list-item *ngFor="let characteristics of phones">
                        {{characteristics.rating}}
                    </md-list-item>
                </md-list>


    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to loop through the array `phone.characteristics` :

```
<div  *ngIf="phones">
   <p>{{phones.description}}</p>
   <md-list *ngIf="dish">
        <md-list-item *ngFor="let characteristic of phones.characteristics">
                    {{characteristic.rating}}
        </md-list-item>
   </md-list>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `phones` variable is accessible in your template as well as all of its properties and nested objects. You can use the dot notation to get those properties.
Here's the way to do what you need:

```
<div  *ngIf="phones">
    <p>{{phones.description}}</p>
    <md-list *ngIf="dish">
          <md-list-item *ngFor="let characteristic of phones.characteristics">
               {{characteristic.rating}}
          </md-list-item>
    </md-list>
</div>
```